# How to encode http query param for redirection in golang

Tags: http, go

I have a golang link redirection module which uses a http server , gets a request and redirects
The problem is with handling chars inside query string , which I have to encode
While I can redirect most chars without any encoding , something like http:// does not work

Should I encode this ?
Sample code is here

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func startHTTP(address string) {
    s := &fasthttp.Server{
        Handler: fastHTTPHandler,
        Name:    "Custom HTTP",
    }
    err := s.ListenAndServe(address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not Start http server  at %s", address)
    }
}

/* main function */
func main() {
    startHTTP("127.0.0.1:9080")
}

func notFound(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Helloworld NOT FOUND\n\n")
}

func handleRedirect(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

    //This link does not carry the original query string on redirection
    link := "https://www.google.com?link=https://www.google.com/movie/2900"

    ctx.Redirect(link, 302)
    ctx.SetStatusCode(302)
}

func fastHTTPHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    fmt.Printf("%v [%v] %v\n", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"), os.Getpid(), string(ctx.URI().RequestURI()))

    switch string(ctx.Path()) {
    case "/goredirect":
        handleRedirect(ctx)
    default:
        notFound(ctx)
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use net/http or ask the author of fasthttp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a URL like that, you have to escape the query string:

```
q,err:=url.QueryEscape("https://www.google.com/movie/2900")
link := "https://www.google.com?link="+q
```

Comment: Alternatively, use [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) which will let you do it programatically and handle everything according to spec.